# How do Google Analytics advanced segment filters work?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to filter people who landed on a specific page and who were also new users (i.e., they landed on my site for the first time through this entry page).

That way I can track loyalty behavior of users who found my site via a specific landing page.

But I'm confused about the difference between using 'AND' in the same filter or creating a brand new filter in the GA's advanced filters.

I can't understand the difference between the two, but they do show slightly different data. Also, the loyalty is much better in the second version (with filters).

Which is the correct way to get the right data?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

including and is a way to drill down into the exact thing you are looking for. It seems you were on the right track; I would put

Landing Page > Contains > URI

AND

User Type > Exactly Matches > New Visitor

If you use them together (I.E) URI of specific Landing page AND New Visitors, you will drill down to only new users who viewed your landing page.

If you create two separate Advanced segments, you will only get comparisons of new users who viewed your website to users who viewed your landing page.

What you could also do is create a new view(If you have Admin Access) and create a filter that only shows new visitors who came to your website via a specific landing page only.

I would say creating the filter in a new view is easier than the Advanced Segment.